# D3js Use element's current color in tooltip

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Been learning D3.js for a couple weeks now. I'm going back and cleaning up some of my code, making it a bit more efficient. I have a paired bar chart, on mouse-over a tooltip is generated. The title in the tooltip matches the color of the particular bar.

[image: tooltip hover]

This is the deisred effect. However, I'm statically setting the color from my color array:

```
d3.select("#tooltip")
        .select("#keyword")
        .style("color", colors[0][2])
        .text(d.keyword);
```

I would assume I could have it select the color of the current bar & apply it in the tooltip on mouseover. How can this be setup? (Maybe I'm mixing things with Jquery and using $this to select.)

I would rather use javascript to detect the color it is hovering over & apply that color. So I need some sort of anonymous function in place of `colors[0][2]`

Drew up a [**Fiddle to play around with full code**](http://jsfiddle.net/enigmarm/Hv867/1/).

Comment: I'm confused.  The color of the tooltip title is changing for me to match the color of the bar my mouse is over....

Comment: right. But I have manually set the color based on my color array `.style("color", colors[0][2]`. I would rather use javascript to detect the color it is hovering over & apply that color. So I need some sort of anonymous function in place of `colors[0][2]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you go:

http://jsfiddle.net/VTJ5G/

Just changed the relevant code in two spots to:

```
d3.select("#tooltip")
    .select("#keyword")
    .style("color", d3.select(this).style("fill"))
    .text(d.keyword);
```

Comment: That is it! Figured this would be a little more effective in the long run. Thanks.

Comment: Does this work with D3 version 4?  Or is the syntax different?

Comment: @Keith I haven't used version 4 myself, so I don't know.